# How can I take data and plot it as a normal distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

New to MATLAB, I want to take a vector data, normalize it, and plot it as a normal distribution. I have code to normalize my data and plot it as a histogram, but it does not come out as a normally distributed, so can someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this. The code below is for normalizing the data:

```
subplot(3, 1, 1)
[x, y] = hist(data, 50);
bar(y, x/trapz(y, x))
```

So this normalizes my histogram but does not make a normally distributed curve. The data is not random and is stored as a vector.

Comment: You can only plot the data "as a normal distribution" if the data comes from a normal distribution.  Your code does not indicate that at all.

Comment: @rayryeng I see, so if my data has a standard deviation of 3, that must mean it is not normally distributed very well?

Comment: The standard deviation is an indication of the spread of your data.  It doesn't indicate that your data is normally distributed.

Comment: @rayryeng But if it is a std of 3, would that not indicate that the data is congregated at +- 3 standard deviations from the mean? So it would not appear Gaussian as it is not congregated at or near the mean.

Comment: Normal distribution means that the data looks like a "bell". If your data doesnt look like that, then you can not interpret the standard deviation and means as if teh data was distributed normally!

Comment: @Jay You can't just assume that your data comes from a Gaussian distribution **unless you know that it is the case**.  Much like when someone presents you with an engine of a car, we can't assume that the engine comes from a Mercedes or BMW unless you **know** it came from that kind of car.  Similarly, when presented with the mean and standard deviation of data, we can't assume the values originate from a Gaussian distribution unless you **know** it came from that kind of distribution before hand.You have not provided any information regarding where your data came from so we can't assume this.

Comment: The data _is_ or _is not_ normally distributed. You can't "plot it as normally distributed". The distribution is of the data, not of the plot

Comment: As an example, try this data: `data=[zeros(100,1); ones(100,1)*100]`. Standard deviation is 50 and mean 50 also, but data is DEFINETLY not located at `-100`~ `200` !! This is because it doesnt follow a normal distribution

Comment: @Jay it may be possible to assume that your data is normally distributed by the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)... and this only works if you have a large amount of samples in your data.  Again, you have not indicated this at all so we're left with more questions than answers.

Comment: @rayryeng I have about 50,000 data points, when I plot the normalized histogram it is not Gaussian, however if I overlay a PDF on it, the PDF is Gaussian, what does this mean?

Comment: I think what I have been meaning to say is that I would like to make the data fit a normal curve, not distribution

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is `histfit` which produces a histogram and fits a distribution to it at the same time. You can choose the number of bins and this distribution to fit as arguments to the function. The example below uses 100 bins for the histogram and fits a normal curve to your data:

```
histfit(data, 100, 'normal')
```

The default value for number of bins is square-root of the number of elements in `data`, rounded up, and the default value for distribution is *normal*. Full documentation for `histfit` is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/histfit.html).